# Boundedness of extension of a continuous function

Tags: general-topology

Let S={(x,y)in R^2|-1<=x<=1,-1<=y<=1} .  Let  A  , the set obtained by removing the origin from S  .    Let f  be a continuous function from A   to  R.If  f can be extended to a continuous function  from  S  to R   then is the image of   f necessarily bounded?If so,why?

Comment: No.  f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2.

Comment: Why introduce A if you are only interested in extending f ffrom S to R?

Comment: @WilliamElliot I believe you have misunderstood his question. He asks whether a continuous $f:A\to R$ that can be extended to a continuous $f:S \to R$ (and not extending from $f:S \to R$ to $f:R^2 \to R$), necessarily has a bounded image $f(S)$. Your example then is not a counterexample because if restricted to $S$, the function is in fact bounded.

Comment: The image is necessarily bounded because $S$ is compact under its usual topology inherited from $R^2$ (continuous image of a compact set is compact, which is bounded in $R$). Taking away at most a point does not affect boundedness, so $f(A)$ is necessarily bounded if it can be extended continuous to $S$.